# how does SSD non-volatile storage work

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, solid-state-devices

Is it because of the charge present in floating gate that SSDs are able to store information without power? If so, how long would the charge remain in floating gate without electricity?

Comment: Have you tried to google "how ssd works"?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, I did go over couple articles which is why I have this question; couldn't find a definite explanation and hence thought to post here. I am new to Hardware and Circuits and hence could be struggling with joining the dots...

Comment: "How ssd works" should definitely (like, first article) lead you to *FLASH memory*, which should lead you to wikipedia, which has a nice explanation. Insufficient research!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can easily find this information using Google. You having trouble "connecting the dots" is not an excuse, that simply means you need to search more and study the subjects you do not understand. You cannot understand how flash memory works if you don't understand MOSFETs for example. You cannot understand MOSFETs if you don't understand Semiconductors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually they use a battery and refresh the memory with a controller on technologies that have don't have a permanent lifetime. Or they design the memory technology for a longer lifetime.

Some Enterprise class SSD's will actually [lose their information](https://www.anandtech.com/show/9248/the-truth-about-ssd-data-retention) if not powered up after a few months.